# Compare with each other, items inside two lists, in a for loop?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

How do I check in Python, if an item of a list is repetead in another list?
I suppose that I should use a FOR loop, to go and check item by item, but I´m stuck in something like this (which I know it´s not correct):

```
def check(a, b):
    for item in b:
        for item1 in a:
            if b[item] in a[item1]:
                b.remove(b[item1])
```

I want to remove repeated elements in the second list in comparision with the first list.

**Edit: I do assume that list a has items that are repeated in list b. Those items can be of any type.**

Desired output:
a=[a,b,c]
b=[c,d,e]

I want to append both lists and print: a b c d e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `a` and `b` do not contain duplicate items that need to be preserved *and* the items are all hashable, you can use Python has a built in [`set`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```
c = list(set(b) - set(a))
# c is now a list of everything in b that is not in a
```

This would work for:

```
a, b = range(7), range(5, 11)
```

but it would *not* work for:

```
a = [1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2]
b = [1, 3, 4]

# After the set operations c would be [2]
# rather than the possibly desired [2, 2]
```

In the case when duplicates are desired you can do the following:

```
set_b = set(b)
c = [x for x in a if x not in b]
```

Using a `set` for `b` will make the lookups `O(1)` rather than `O(N)` (which will not matter for small lists).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python's [set](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) operations without the need for loops:

```
>>> a = [1,2]
>>> b = [2]
>>> set(a) - set(b)
set([1])
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `set` command and `list` to get the list back.

```
d = list(set(a + b))
```

You can use `list.sort()` if you want to sort the list as well.